# Mongocxx X509 Authentication Error - SSLHandshakeFailed","errmsg":"no SSL certificate provided by peer; connection rejected"

Tags: c++, mongodb, x509, mongo-cxx-driver, self-signed-certificate

I am Trying to connect to mongoDb using x509Authentication. I have generated the self signed certificates.
Even I have provided the exact path to the Certificates in my code still I am getting bellow error in mongodb server:

{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-14T15:14:20.108+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn5","msg":"connection ended","attr":{"remote":"192.168.43.20:62215","connectionCount":1}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-14T15:14:47.154+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn4","msg":"connection ended","attr":{"remote":"192.168.43.20:62187","connectionCount":0}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-14T17:03:04.641+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"192.168.43.20:62813","sessionId":6,"connectionCount":1}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-14T17:03:04.720+05:30"},"s":"E",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23280,   "ctx":"conn6","msg":"No SSL certificate provided by peer; connection rejected"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-14T17:03:04.720+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22988,   "ctx":"conn6","msg":"Error receiving request from client. Ending connection from remote","attr":{"error":{"code":141,"codeName":"SSLHandshakeFailed","errmsg":"no SSL certificate provided by peer; connection rejected"},"remote":"192.168.43.20:62813","connectionId":6}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-14T17:03:04.721+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn6","msg":"connection ended","attr":{"remote":"192.168.43.20:62813","connectionCount":0}}

My Code:-

std::string ca_file = "D:/Certs/my.crt";
std::string pem_file = "D:/Certs/user.pem";

```
/*if (FILE *file = fopen(ca_file.c_str(), "r")) {
    fclose(file);
}
if (FILE *file = fopen(pem_file.c_str(), "r")) {
    fclose(file);
}*/
std::fstream filestream;
filestream.open(ca_file);
if (filestream.fail())
{
    std::cout << "certificate not passed";
}
else 
{
    std::cout << "certificate passed"<<std::endl;
}



tls_options.ca_file(ca_file);
tls_options.ca_dir("D:/Certs/");
tls_options.pem_file(pem_file);
tls_options.pem_password("1234");
tls_options.allow_invalid_certificates(true);
client_options.tls_opts(tls_options);
m_cpp_client = NULL;

try
{
    mongocxx::instance inst{};
    mongocxx::client conn{ mongocxx::uri{"mongodb://192.168.43.20:27017/?authMechanism=MONGODB-X509&tls=true"},client_options};
    // auto collection = conn["test"]["restaurants"];
    mongocxx::database db = conn["admin"];
    auto cursor1 = db.list_collections();
    for (const bsoncxx::document::view& doc : cursor1)
    {
        bsoncxx::document::element ele = doc["name"];
        std::string name = ele.get_utf8().value.to_string();
        std::cout << name << std::endl;

    }
}
```

Please let me know if you can help me

Comment: Can you connect via mongo shell with that pem file? I also don't understand why you are providing ca path, ca dir and allow invalid certificates  - these options all override one another essentially.

Comment: Yes I am able to connect to mongo shell using following commands:=

Comment: mongo --tls --tlsCertificateKeyFile "D:\Certs\user.pem" --authenticationDatabase '$external' --authenticationMechanism MONGODB-X509 --host 192.168.43.20

Comment: mongo --tls --tlsCertificateKeyFile "D:\Certs\user.pem" --tlsCAFile "D:\Certs\my.crt" --authenticationDatabase '$external' --authenticationMechanism MONGODB-X509 --host 192.168.43.20

Comment: I suggest referencing the documentation you are following from the question and adding an mcve.

Comment: Thanks for your response @D.SM but could you please let me know what is the issue in my code?

Comment: It looks reasonable to me but I do not use the C++ driver myself and thus I may be overlooking some finer details, which is why I suggested you make an mcve.